# Is it possible to have list of functions in a jit function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jit, numba

I'm just wondering if it's possible to use a list of functions or even a dictionary of functions within a jit function.

e.g.

```
def func1():
    pass

def func2():
    pass

list_ = [func1, func2]

@njit
def jit_func(list_):
    # do something with list of functions
```

Having trouble implementing something like this so wondering if it's possible/if there's a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the decorator on the fundamental functions and use a lambda or a generic f function to run a list of functions.
If you have lots of functions to run, you can use Pool.map to run the functions in parallel and collect all the output as a list of results.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


@njit
def func1():
    return 'func1'

@njit
def func2():
    return 'func2'

def f(fun):
    '''
    Run a function.
    '''
    return fun()

list_ = [func1, func2]

with Pool(2) as p:
    r = p.map(f, list_)


>>>r
['func1', 'func2']
```

Comment: Thanks but my aim isn't to jit the initial functions, more just have access and be able to iterate over the initial functions within a jitted function.